# Execute "sudo mavproxy.py" from Python script

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to execute this command `sudo mavproxy.py` from a python script on raspberrypi. I can execute this in the shell and see it load.

The code I have for my current test is:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('sudo mavproxy.py')
```

Running this the code executes however looking at the terminal window nothing happens. I'm not sure whether it is executing correctly.

Comment: try `sudo /full/path/to/mavproxy.py` . (Just a guess). Good luck.

Comment: Note that `sudo` is often configured to deliberately refuse to work when run in any context where no TTY is available. The default configuration is designed for use by human operators, not scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass the arguments as a list:

```
subprocess.call(['sudo', 'mavproxy.py'])
```

Or use `shell=True`:

```
subprocess.call('sudo mavproxy.py', shell=True)
```

The documentation is pretty clear about this.  How did you learn to try it that way?

Comment: I had looked at other peoples examples, however i've never used python before and noticed that there's different ways to do it dependent on what version I am using. So was unclear about how to go about it. When executing the script should i see the terminal window open and execute the command?

Comment: @Hamish, depends on your platform. On sane/UNIXy platforms, no, you won't see a terminal opened.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

import os.path

os.system('sudo python /full/path/to/mavproxy.py')
```

Comment: Can you provide some kind of explanation for how your answer works?

Comment: Boo, hiss; `os.system` is obsolescent; [`subprocess` is the preferred replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system).

Answer (score -1):

Import the call function from the subprocess module

```
 from subprocess import call
 call('sudo mavproxy.py', shell=True)
```

Comment: Why  would this behave differently in any way from the OP's original code?